# Can DVD+R hold .iso files and boot up via to bios?

Tags: dvd, bootable

This seems like a stupid question, I know, but can I take a DVD+R and use that as a .iso image DVD and then boot a program from the bios with it? If not, what type of CD do I need?

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, the type of medium the ISO file is on is irrelevant so long as it is a bootable ISO.

Comment: Yeah, +R and -R should not make a difference

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure what you mean by boot a program from bios with it?

Do you mean boot an ISO image as if it was a physical dvd?
It's tricky but can be done with Grub2 http://michael-prokop.at/blog/2009/05/25/boot-an-iso-via-grub2/

edit - sorry misunderstood.
If you just want to make a physical DVD from an iso image then just right click on the iso and select "burn image" in Windows7.  Or your DVD writing software probably has a burn ISO option.

Note this is different from copying an ISO onto a DVD - you need to burn it as an image so the format inside the iso is copied to the dvd as a whole

Comment: So I can write a .iso file to a DVD+R disc and then boot the OS on that disc to the bios?

Comment: Do you mean have the BIOS boot from the DVD-drive instead of the HDD? Yes, that should work as long as you change the settings in your BIOS

Comment: Sorry misunderstood - yes writing an ISO file to a DVD is trivial. Doesn;'t matter if it's +R or -R.

Comment: So, the fact that the disc is a DVD+R doesn't matter?

Comment: No problem, almost all drives these days are dual standard.